# Flags attribute vs HashSet

Tags: c#, data-structures, enums, set

I noticed that newer versions of C# allow the enum construct to be adapted to represent a set of bitwise flags by use of the [flags] attribute.

It seems to me that C# already has a perfectly good construct called HashSet to represent a set, and I have often used Hashsets of enums in my code. Are there any examples, other than efficiency of processing, where a flags enum provides functionality that cannot be done using a normal set?

IMHO a traditional enum is semantically so different from a set of flags, it seems a complete bastardization to use an attribute to turn one into the other.

Comment: `Flags` has been since the beginning and it has no semantic value. The only functionality it has, it changing the way `ToString` behaves. It is still up to you to provide the correct values.

Comment: Some refactoring and code analysis tools also picks up on its presence.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "traditional enum," but I remember working on C code 30 years ago in which those "bastardized" enums were used. As far as I can tell, the technique of using an enum to hold flag values  has been around as long as `enum` has been in the C language.

Answer (score 2):

For example *attributes*:

```
  // MyAttribute can be applied to constructors, events and methods only
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Event | AttributeTargets.Method)]
  public class MyAttribute {
    ... 
  }
```

you can't use `HashSet<T>` for

```
  AttributeTargets.Constructor | AttributeTargets.Event | AttributeTargets.Method
```

in the context; the only (readable) possibility is `AttributeTargets` enum with `[Flags]` option

Comment: Though you could create a hashset with those 3 values in it. The reason why a flags enum is a good choice for an attribute is that attributes requires constant parameters, and a hashet isn't.

Answer (score 2):

> I noticed that newer versions of C# allow the enum construct to be adapted to represent a set of bitwise flags by use of the [flags] attribute.

I'm pretty sure it was there in .NET 1.0. It definitely was in .NET 1.1. The flag technique would have been around from the earliest experimental work on .NET since it's inherent to the use of binary representations of integers, whether a language provides a tool to help reflect that or not.

> It seems to me that C# already has a perfectly good construct called HashSet to represent a set.

Since .NET 3.5 it has. Until 2.0 .NET didn't even have generics.

> IMHO a traditional enum is semantically so different from a set of flags,

Traditionally enums have been used for binary flags for a very long time. This helped enforce typing on the use of integer values for binary flags which has been a technique used from the very early days of computer science. A classic case would be the permissions flags of unix file systems, where a number is composed of bits representing read, write and execute permissions for different classes of user.

> I have often used Hashsets of enums in my code

If these enum represent flag values, this is frankly bizarre. Among other things, you couldn't have a `const` HashSet. This sounds like an extreme case of premature pessimisation.

Comment: @JimMischel premature pessimisation comes up a lot when one thinks one has a clever variant, but finds that in the end one has just made the code slower, larger, more bug-prone and harder to maintain before any need to be slower, larger, more bug-prone and harder to maintain has been found.

Comment: Oh, I'm familiar with the the effect; I might even have done it a time or two myself. Just haven't heard it called "premature pessimisation" before.

Comment: @JimMischel yes, it's the realisation that one has done it oneself that produces the humorous effect. I'd thought it my own coinage when I first used it, but apparently others came up with it first.